# Find the sum of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k \dbinom{n+i}{i}$

Tags: combinatorics

For $k\geq 1$ find the value of:

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k \dbinom{n+i}{i}$

How are solutions to such problems approached in general?

Answer (score 2):

**Most**(Not always though) problems of this time can be proved using Identity: 
$$ \binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1} $$
In this problem we have ,
$$ \sum_{i=0}^k \dbinom{n+i}{i}= \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n+i+1}{i} -\binom{n+i}{i-1}+1$$
Which is a telescopic sum:
$$ = 1+ \binom{n+2}{1}-\binom{n+1}{0}+ \binom{n+3}{2}- \binom{n+2}{1}+ \cdots + \binom{n+k+1}{k}-\binom{n+k}{k-1}= \binom{n+k+1}{k} \Box$$

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the pattern in the Pascal triangle and think how you can "percolate" things down until you obtain $n+k+1\choose k$. Once you have the result, you can prove it directly by induction (on $k$).

Comment: Can you elaborate?